# Возврат определенного атрибута класса по вызову экземпляра класса (переменой)

Tags: python, ооп

```
class PythonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__some_dict = {"key_1": 12}


inst_1 = PythonClass()
json.dumps(inst_1)  # >> Должен возвращaться словарь "inst_1.__some_dict"
```

Вместо объекта переменой должен возвращаться `__some_dict` , а не объект класса. Есть ли метод или какая-нибудь тонкость для данной реализации? Иначе не могу масштабировать проект без переписывания тонны кода.

Comment: [Расширите `JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: @anton Единственный вариант?

Comment: Гм.. не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Если вам от класса нужен только словарь, так и замените класс на функцию с тем же именем, которая будет возвращать словарь.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, можно, конечно, вот так сделать:

```
class PythonClass:
    def __new__(cls):
        return {"key_1": 12}


inst_1 = PythonClass()
print(inst_1)
```

Это будет именно то, о чём вы спрашиваете, - класс, который при инстанцировании создаёт словарь, вместо объекта класса.

Но я бы порекомендовал обратить внимание на вариант из комментов - функцию, которая просто имеет имя, как у вашего класса:

```
def PythonClass():
    return {"key_1": 12}


inst_1 = PythonClass()
print(inst_1)
```

Либо, если задача именно в том, чтобы объект класса мог сериализоваться в json, то можно написать кастомный энкодер:

```
# Мы не меняем реализацию самого класса
class PythonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__some_dict = {"key_1": 12}


inst_1 = PythonClass()


# Вместо этого мы делаем энкодер, который знает, как сериализовать наш класс в словарь
import json


class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, PythonClass):
            return obj._PythonClass__some_dict
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


# И используем этот декодер для сериализации в json
dumped = json.dumps(inst_1, cls=CustomEncoder)
print(dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __dict__(self):
    return self.__some_dict
```

`__dict__` - магическая функция, которая выполняется, когда к объекту пытаются обратиться как к словарю (преобразовать в словарь в нашем случае)

Comment: Нет, `__dict__` не работает: всё равно выдает `TypeError: Object of type PythonClass is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: Потому что он не является словаре подобным. Если вам уж совсем не хочется преобразовывать в словарь через маг. функцию, то просто наследуйте объект словаря.

Comment: Но проще будет преобразовать в словарь через маг. функцию.